# Scrape data from show more button on same page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

From website need to scrape odds. At the end of the row have a button on which need to click and from there to scrape odds.

Here is an example of a row for one match

```
<div class="event-row" event="[object Object]" number-of-displayed-markets="3">
   <div class="event-container">
      <div class="event-wrap">
         <div class="event-wrap-time timelist"> 04:00 </div>
         <div class="event-wrap-category has-tooltip" data-original-title="null">
            <div class="flag-wrap">
               <div class="flags-0-5625">
                  <div class="flag flag-mex"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tournament-abbreviation"> MEX </div>
         </div>
         <div class="event-wrap-name pointer"><span>Puebla - Guadalajara</span></div>
         <!----><!---->
      </div>
      <div class="event-outcomes-wrap">
         <div class="event-outcomes-row">
            <div class="event-outcomes-container">
               <!---->
               <div class="event-outcomes-odd pointer"> 2.50 </div>
               <div class="event-outcomes-odd pointer"> 2.90 </div>
               <div class="event-outcomes-odd pointer"> 3.10 </div>
            </div>
            <!---->
         </div>
         <div class="event-outcomes-row">
            <div class="event-outcomes-container">
               <!---->
               <div class="event-outcomes-odd pointer"> 1.40 </div>
               <div class="event-outcomes-odd pointer"> 1.60 </div>
               <div class="event-outcomes-odd pointer"> 2.85 </div>
               <div class="event-outcomes-odd pointer"> 5.85 </div>
            </div>
            <!---->
         </div>
         <div class="event-outcomes-row">
            <div class="event-outcomes-container">
               <!---->
               <div class="event-outcomes-odd pointer"> 2.25 </div>
               <div class="event-outcomes-odd pointer"> 6.30 </div>
               <div class="event-outcomes-odd pointer"> 3.65 </div>
               <div class="event-outcomes-odd pointer"> 6.25 </div>
            </div>
            <!---->
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="event-markets-count pointer">
         <div class="event-markets-count-value">+56</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

After clicking on the button `<div class="event-markets-count-value">+56</div>` got something like a popup window on the same page and from there I need to scrape `<div class="eventview-market-name"> D C  </div>` odds `1X X2 and 12`. I need to do same for every match on page.

```
<div class="eventview-container noselect">
   <div class="eventview-content">
      <div class="eventview-header" event="[object Object]">
         <div class="eventview-header-content">
            <div class="eventview-header-event-name">
               <div class="home-team-name">Puebla</div>
               <div class="team-names-separator"> - </div>
               <div class="away-team-name">Guadalajara</div>
            </div>
            <div class="eventview-header-details">
               <!----><span> Sun 21.11. 04:00 -  </span><!----><span>Mexico 1</span>
            </div>
            <!---->
         </div>
         <i class="icon icon-close"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="eventview-bet-groups">
         <div class="eventview-bet-groups-button active"><span> All </span></div>
         <div class="eventview-bet-groups-button"><span> Basics </span></div>
         <div class="eventview-bet-groups-button"><span> Goals </span></div>
         <div class="eventview-bet-groups-button"><span> Both teams to score </span></div>
         <div class="eventview-bet-groups-button"><span> Combo </span></div>
         <div class="eventview-bet-groups-button dropdown">
            <span> More </span><i class="icon dropdown-icon icon-arrow-down-a"></i><!---->
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="eventview-body-wrap">
         <!---->
                     <div class="eventview-market-wrap">
                        <div class="eventview-market-wrap">
                           <!---->
                           <div class="event-markets-wrap">
                              <div class="eventview-market">
                                 <div market="[object Object]" class="eventview-market-header pointer">
                                    <div class="eventview-market-name"> Finish  </div>
                                    <div class="eventview-icons-group">
                                       <div class="market-description-tooltip has-tooltip" data-original-title="null"><i class="icon icon-info-secondary"></i></div>
                                       <div class="favourite-market"><i class="icon icon-star"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="eventview-outcome-wrapper eventview-market-outcomes expanded">
                                    <div class="eventview-outcome" outcome="[object Object]" marketoutcomeslength="3" market="[object Object]" selectoutcome="function () { [native code] }">
                                       <div class="eventview-outcome-name">1</div>
                                       <div class="eventview-outcome-odd"> 2.50 </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="eventview-outcome" outcome="[object Object]" marketoutcomeslength="3" market="[object Object]" selectoutcome="function () { [native code] }">
                                       <div class="eventview-outcome-name">X</div>
                                       <div class="eventview-outcome-odd"> 2.90 </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="eventview-outcome" outcome="[object Object]" marketoutcomeslength="3" market="[object Object]" selectoutcome="function () { [native code] }">
                                       <div class="eventview-outcome-name">2</div>
                                       <div class="eventview-outcome-odd"> 3.10 </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="eventview-market-wrap">
                        <div class="eventview-market-wrap">
                           <!---->
                           <div class="event-markets-wrap">
                              <div class="eventview-market">
                                 <div market="[object Object]" class="eventview-market-header pointer">
                                    <div class="eventview-market-name"> D C  </div>
                                    <div class="eventview-icons-group">
                                       <div class="market-description-tooltip has-tooltip" data-original-title="null"><i class="icon icon-info-secondary"></i></div>
                                       <div class="favourite-market"><i class="icon icon-star"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="eventview-outcome-wrapper eventview-market-outcomes expanded">
                                    <div class="eventview-outcome" outcome="[object Object]" marketoutcomeslength="3" market="[object Object]" selectoutcome="function () { [native code] }">
                                       <div class="eventview-outcome-name">1X</div>
                                       <div class="eventview-outcome-odd"> 1.34 </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="eventview-outcome" outcome="[object Object]" marketoutcomeslength="3" market="[object Object]" selectoutcome="function () { [native code] }">
                                       <div class="eventview-outcome-name">12</div>
                                       <div class="eventview-outcome-odd"> 1.40 </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="eventview-outcome" outcome="[object Object]" marketoutcomeslength="3" market="[object Object]" selectoutcome="function () { [native code] }">
                                       <div class="eventview-outcome-name">X2</div>
                                       <div class="eventview-outcome-odd"> 1.50 </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                           <div class="event-markets-wrap">
                              <div class="eventview-market">
                                 <div market="[object Object]" class="eventview-market-header pointer">
                                    
                                    <div class="eventview-icons-group">
                                       <div class="market-description-tooltip has-tooltip" data-original-title="null"><i class="icon icon-info-secondary"></i></div>
                                       <div class="favourite-market"><i class="icon icon-star"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!---->
</div>
```

My not working code:

```
box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="timelist-events-wrap"]')
single_row_events = box.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'event-row')

for match in single_row_events:
    more_odds = match.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'event-markets-count').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    goals = match.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/span').click()
    odds_event = match.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]')
    odds_events.append(odds_event)
    close = match.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/i').click()

for odds_event in teams:
    for odds_event in odds_events:
        for n, box in enumerate(odds_event):
            rows = box.find_elements(By.XPATH, './.')
            if n == 0:
                dc.append(rows[0].text)
```

This clicking on `more_odds` but can't scrape and store in an array.

Show me error `Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Pete\OneDrive\Documents\Scrape\bets\bbet.py", line 57, in <module> more_odds = match.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'event-markets-count').click()`

Answer (score 0):

Xpath that you've used isn't relative, they are absolute. Making them brittle in nature. I have corrected a few `locators`, and I have also induce `WebDriverWait` (`ExplicitWait`)

**Code:**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(box, 30)
odds_events = []

single_row_events = box.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='event-row']")
print("How many rows  ?", len(single_row_events))

for match in single_row_events:
    try:
        time.sleep(.5)
        match.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='event-markets-count pointer']").click()
        print('Row should have clicked')
        odds_event = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='away-team-name']"))).text
        odds_events.append(odds_event)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Now show me error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pete\OneDrive\Documents\Scrape\bets\bbet.py", line 104, in <module>
    rows = box.find_element(By.XPATH, './.')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element'` and only scrapes odds for the first match.